# Node js route working on localhost but not on AWS ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, backend

I am working on a project right now and I have created an express server that serves HTML files here is the code for the server

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const staticRequests = require('./Routes/staticRequestHandler');
const individualRegister = require('./Routes/IndividualRegistrationHandler');
const individualPaymentHandler = require('./Routes/individualPaymentHandler');
const instituteRegister = require('./Routes/registrationHandler');
const paymentHandler = require('./Routes/paymentHandler');
const {emailHandler} = require('./Routes/emailHandler');
const loginHandler = require('./Routes/loginHandler');
const examHandler = require('./Routes/examHandler');
const instituteRegistrationHandler = require('./Routes/excelFileHandler');
const instituteIndexRoutes = require('./Routes/institute-index');
const {verifyEndPoint} = require('./Routes/phoneVerificationHandler');
const reviewHandler = require('./Routes/reviewHandler');
const coordRegHandler = require('./Routes/coordinatorRegHandler');
const verifyCaptcha =require('./Routes/verifyCaptcha');
const saveContact = require('./Routes/contact');

// MiddleWare
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Routes for serving HTML

//public paths
app.use('/IndividualPaymentLink?:id', express.static('public/html files/individualPayment.html'))
app.use('/register', express.static('public/html files/student-register.html'));
app.use('/instituteRegister', express.static('public/html files/institute-register.html'));
app.use('/login', express.static('public/html files/login.html'))
app.use('/forgotPassword', express.static('public/html files/forgotPassword.html'))
app.use('/resetPassword', express.static('public/html files/resetPassword.html'))
app.use('/institutePage', express.static('public/html files/institute-index.html'))
app.use('/examRegistration', express.static('public/html files/addExams.html'))
app.use('/getStudentDetails?:examId', express.static('public/html files/displayStudents.html'))
app.use('/payment?:orderId', express.static('public/html files/paymentPage.html'))
app.use('/FAQs', express.static('public/html files/FAQ.html'))
app.use('/SISO', express.static('public/html files/SISO.html'))
app.use('/SIMO', express.static('public/html files/SIMO.html'))
app.use('/SIEO', express.static('public/html files/SIEO.html'))
app.use('/GRADS', express.static('public/html files/GRADS.html'))
app.use('/FINANCE', express.static('public/html files/FINANCE.html'))
app.use('/aboutus', express.static('public/html files/aboutus.html'))
app.use('/reviews', express.static('public/html files/reviews.html'))
app.use('/coordinator', express.static('public/html files/coordinator.html'))
app.use('/SICO', express.static('public/html files/SICO.html'))
app.use('/NGvUqENEBkY3ZFTJSDQfXcIQfObhfIuavKbWZWn4GOYwleCXcz', express.static('public/html files/thankYou.html'))
app.use('/schedule', express.static('public/html files/schedule.html'))



//routes

app.get(['/getFAQs', '/getReviews', '/getAnnouncements', '/getStats', '/countries', '/getStates', '/getCities?:state', '/getDates'],staticRequests)
app.post('/registerIndividual', individualRegister);
app.get('/individualOrderDetails?:orderId', individualPaymentHandler) 
app.post(['/studpaymentSuccess', '/studpaymentFailure'], individualPaymentHandler)
app.post('/register-institute', instituteRegister);
app.get('/verify', emailHandler); // verify institute email
app.post('/recoverPassword', emailHandler);
app.get('/verifyToken?:token', loginHandler);
app.post(['/reset', '/login-institute'], loginHandler); // reset institute password
app.get(['/getExams?:type','/getPrice?:totalExams?:totalStudents'], examHandler);
app.post('/registerInstituteExam', instituteRegistrationHandler);
app.post('/submitReview', reviewHandler);
app.get('/getRegisteredExams?:name',instituteIndexRoutes);
app.post(['/registerCoordinator', '/sendOtp'], coordRegHandler);
app.post('/verifyCaptcha', verifyCaptcha);
app.post(['/paymentSuccess', '/paymentFailure'], paymentHandler)
app.get('/orderDetails?:orderId', instituteRegistrationHandler)
app.post('/saveContact', saveContact);
app.get('/getRegisteredStudents?:examId', instituteIndexRoutes);
app.get('/S/:id', verifyEndPoint); // verify institute mobile no
app.get('/getPincodeDetails?:pincode', staticRequests); // get state and city from pincode

app.use('*', express.static('public/html files/404.html'))

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}!`));
```

**This above code works perfectly on localhost, everything works fine but I have an AWS ec2 ubuntu instance. when I deploy this code over there every route except for the one below works perfectly**

```
app.use('/IndividualPaymentLink?:id', express.static('public/html files/individualPayment.html'))
```

When I try to go to the above link I am redirected to the 404 pages?
I have pretty much read through all possible examples on StackOverflow and everywhere else, but I am unable to understand the problem?

Comment: For what it's worth; this is the first `use` in your list so if you need an urgent solution, you could try adding another `use` in front of it to a dummy page ?

Comment: How are you getting it onto to EC2? Does the HTML file exist on it?

Comment: Yes the html files are there and I'll try your solution and let you know about it!

Comment: Also I have previously tried moving it below a few routes but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved the problem was that the file name had the wrong casing the **original name was InstitutePayment and I used institutePayment**.